# How to select $6$ shoes from $12$ pairs of shoes

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> How to select $6$ shoes from $12$ pairs of shoes where in the selected shoes no two are from the same pair?

- that is, how many ways can this be done?

My solution is the following:

Since the $6$ shoes have to belong to different pairs, we select $6$ pairs out of $12$ pairs and that is $\binom{12}6$. But I think I am missing something because we can take the right or the left shoe, but I don't know how to consider this too. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for the number of ways in which you can do this?

Comment: @Frpzzd Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to find the number of ways to select $6$ shoes from $12$ pairs in which no two are from the same pair, then the number of ways to do this is the same as the number of ways to select $6$ shoes from $12$ different shoes (since we only want to count the non-duplicates). Therefore the answer would be $\binom{12}6$ and your answer would be correct. However, you are concerned that the right and left shoes should be counted differently, so I will address that case as well. For each of the $\binom{12}6$ ways to pick $6$ shoes, there are $2^6$ different ways that their "footednesses" could be arranged (since each shoe is right or left, and there are $6$ of them). Then the final answer should be $\binom{12}6\cdot 2^6$.